# What is the linux equivalent for dos command: dir /s /ah

Tags: linux, command-line

In DOS, the command `dir /s /ah` will recurse through every subdirectory and show all files with the "hidden" attribute.

What is the linux equivalent?

Answer (score 10):

The standard linux filesystems don't come with a "hidden" attribute for files, but convention is that files with names starting with a dot are not shown by e.g. `ls`. You can find these with with `find`

```
find . -name '.*'
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually use `ls -lAR` which recurses through a directory tree, showing file attributes and any 'hidden' files (commonly called 'dot files' because they start with a dot ('.').  You could also replace the 'A' with 'a' to show the current and parent directory in each, but except for the top-level directory, all are shown in the parent's directory.

Comment: That also shows the non-hidden files.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following aliases in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias l.='ls -CAF --ignore=\*'
alias ll.='ls -CAlhF --ignore=\*'
```

They show dotfiles in the current directory. In case you want to recurse through subdirectories, add the `-R` switch to `ls`.